# What will be the sudo -i password when I only used ssh file to login?

Tags: server, ssh, login, password

I don't know if anyone would understand from title, but I couldn't summarize it.

So, I am using ssh file when logging in to my server, like this:

```
ssh -i/path/to/file root@ip_address
```

I want to disable direct root access and use another user while logging in to my server and use `sudo -i` to switch to the root user.

I don't have that much experience with servers nor ubuntu, but last time I used ubuntu, I didn't use any kind of file while connecting to the server, I just wrote `ssh user@ip_address` and was using `sudo -i` to switch on the root access.

I am wondering, if I were to disable direct root access, what password will I use when I run the `sudo -i` command. Because the ssh file is on my computer, and I won't be able to access it from the server, so there should be some other password to use.

Comment: Should I even disable root If I am using private key to access the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should type the password of the user you are logging as. It doesn't matter that you did login using the ssh key. When you created that user account you probably set some password for it (or, if you didn't, you should do this now). You must use that password for sudo.

Or, you can add the following line to the `/etc/sudoers` file (it's best to edit this file using the `visudo` command which guarantees that the system will properly apply changes):

`youruser     ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL`

where `youruser` is the username you use to login. This allows `youruser` to use `sudo` without typing any password.

Comment: is it safe to give sudo access to user without any password?

Comment: Found answer to my comment ^ from google, thanks.